# Integral divergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I´m trying to solve this problem about integral convergence, and I would be happy for any help.

I shoul find out for what values of $a$ is this integral convergent:

$$\int_0^\infty \text{arccot}^ax\,\cos{x}\,dx $$

Near the zero, there is no problem.

The problem is near the infinity - as the $ lim_{x\to\infty} \ arccotg^a{x} \ = 0$ if and only if $a>0$, this function is also monotonic on the inteval $[0,\infty)$ and the primitive function of $cos{\ x}$ is bounded, according to Dirichlet criterion, the integral is convergent for any $a>0$.

However, I really don't know how to show that this integral is divergent for $a \le 0$.

I've spent quite a lot of time on it, however, I have no idea what should I do.

As I've said, I would be really happy for any help or hint.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $x$, $\operatorname{arccot}{x}$ is asymptotic to $1/x$ (because $\cot{y} \sim 1/y$ for $y \to 0$). Hence, for $x \to \infty$, the integral converges only if
$$ \int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{x}}{x^a} \, dx $$
does. For $a \leqslant 0$, the integrand here oscillates, with oscillations that increase in magnitude. Hence the integral does not have a finite value (write it as an alternating series and note that the terms do not converge to zero, so the series diverges).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn´t know that I can use this (that arccot x is asymptotic to 1/x) - why this is correct solution? For me, this seems to be something like limit comparison test, but I can´t use it here, as cos x isn´t only negative or only positive function...

Comment: Notice the integrand is negative on intervals where $\cos{x}$ is, and positive when $\cos{x}$ is. These alternate and are the same length, so you can split the integral at the zeros of the cosine to make an alternating series, which diverges since its terms don't tend to zero.

Comment: Oh, thanks, now it's absolutely clear for me, thank you really much!